# React Native MFE release build issue

Tags: react-native

Hi I am getting error in react native MFE release apk.

com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: ReferenceError: Property '*webpack_require*' doesn't exist, js engine:
get@1:590815
anonymous@1:21111
loadModuleImplementation@1:14516
guardedLoadModule@1:14028
metroRequire@1:13699
global@1:13255

```
at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:65)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:188)
at com.facebook.jni.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
```

Project link: [1]: https://github.com/irshadvali/VERSIONAPP